# Create new records on before_save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback

While creating new records. I need to create more records for the same model.

Example ::

```
class XYZ < ActiveRecord
 def before_save
   # At this point object is already initialized ..
   # And it's containing values.
   # At this point i want to create 10 more records for the same class.
   # something like this
   XYZ.new(:att1 => value1,:att2 => value2,:att3 => self.att1)
 end
end
```

How may i handle this type of scenario ?
On which call back i have to create more records for the same model ?

Comment: Do you want the before_save to be triggered for *those*, too?

Comment: @Mark Thomas Yes validations and callback needs to be fire on those.

Comment: How do you plan to stop the endless loop created by before_saves being called for your extra records created by before_saves?

Comment: Then welcome to an infinite loop.

Comment: That's why i am confused how may i handle this type of scenario..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this sounds like bad engineering, try to rethink your model in a way that makes what you need. 
maybe if you need to create 10 models of something, do not use the activerecord hooks, otherwise you might incur in infine loops.

I would recommend

```
class XYZ < ActiveRecord
 def self.create10(original_xyz)
   10.times do
     clone = original_xyz.clone
     clone.save
   end
 end
end
```

and where in your controller or wherever you have the need to create 10 more, call:

```
new_xyz = XYZ.new(:att1 => value1,:att2 => value2,:att3 => self.att1)
new_xyz.save
XYZ.create10(new_xyz)
```

but if you really need to create 10 more on a hook (like before save), do:

```
class XYZ < ActiveRecord

 before_save create10

 attr_acessor :cloned 

 def create10
   return if cloned # this will prevent infinit loooooooooooooooop
   10.times do
     clone = self.clone
     clone.cloned = true
     clone.save
   end
 end

end
```

I did not run this, so, try it first.

Answer (score 0):

```
class XYZ < ActiveRecord
 def after_initialize
   # At this point object is already initialized ..
   # And it's containing values.
   # At this point i want to create 10 moew records for the same class.
   # something like this
   #XYZ.new(:att1 => value1,:att2 => value2,:att3 => self.att1)
   x = 10 #an integer
   x.times do |task|
     Model.create(:key => :value)
   end
  end
end
```

Comment: But Before creating other objects i need to check validation for existing object. And Validations and Callbacks needs to be fire on other records too.

Comment: Why are you creating instances of Model? OP wants new XYZs. 'task' is also unecessary, as is a reference to 10. 10.times {} is fine.

Comment: @Dave I have a task like if user will enter one record than in the background i have to distribute that record in 10 more rows. One row for user entered and 10 other rows for calculated ones. So how may i handle that type of scenario ?